# get Image thumbnail Resize in custom Class magento 2

Tags: product, catalog, image, thumbnail

I am getting my images in the array.

I need to check the if image in the array is empty then it should be replaced with the thumbnail image.

Here is my code :

```
if (is_null($imageData->getData('demo_promo'))
```

Can I resize the placeholder for specific class as I am using:

```
$this->imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image')
```

Please help me to replace the thumbnail image instead of the empty demo_promo in the array above.
I tried many things but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, Hope it will work.

```
$imageArr =  $imageData->getData('demo_promo');
```

// check variable is array or not

```
if(is_array($imageArr)){
    echo "It is an Array";
}
```

//Check imageArr is empty

```
if(empty($imageArr)){
    echo "Given Array is empty";
}else{
    echo "Given Array is not empty <br>";
}
```

Using `Count` function

```
var_dump($imageArr);

if(count($imageArr) > 0) {
    echo "Given Array is not empty <br>";
}
```

Comment: I know array is empty just want to replace with the magento default thumbnail

Comment: I have edit the question related to the Resize Place holder image.Please if you have any solution please share